# Replacement for Quicken 2007

Tags: macos, software-recommendation

Now that I've upgraded to Lion, Quicken 2007 is history. I need a good replacement that automatically downloads credit card and bank statements from major cards and banks. I need to track investments, too. Importing of old Quicken data would be required, too. Quicken Essentials doesn't fit the bill for me.

I have looked at Money and Moneywell. Both have their strong points, but they don't do everything on the list above. Moneydance is written in Java and I don't like the non-Mac OS look and feel.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[iBank](http://www.iggsoftware.com/ibank/) from IGG software is available in the [Mac App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ibank/id402422773?mt=12), and has been a great replacement (and upgrade) from quicken. It also includes direct Quicken import.

They are also running a '[Spring Break Sale](http://www.iggsoftware.com/ibank/springbreak.php)' That will take off 25% if you are currently using Moneywell, Quicken for Mac, or Quicken Essentials.

[image: iBank]

Answer (score 2):

In an attempt to replace Quicken 2003 for Windows, I ended up on [Moneywell](http://nothirst.com/moneywell/). It has a companion iOS app which allows me to enter transactions on the go and sync via [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com).

It isn't perfect, but I like it.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at a number of alternatives before concluding that there isn't an alternative as comprehensive as Quicken/Windows.  You are going to have to choose between sacrificing some functionality with a native Mac app (hoping for future updates) or running Quicken Windows under Boot Camp/VMware/Parallels/Virtual Box.

iBank is another alternative although Moneydance seems to win most of the time when people compare them (hating the Moneydance look all the way).

Comment: Moneydance is written in Java and is cross-platform. Seldom a good combination for a real mac-like look and feel.

Answer (score 0):

You might look at [SEE Finance](http://scimonocesoftware.com/seefinance/). Lacks tags, otherwise well-featured. (Not affiliated with company.)

Answer (score 0):

Intuit has just announced that they are releasing a Lion-compatible version of Quicken 2007 "soon". [Press release](http://quicken.intuit.com/support/help/lion-compatible-quicken-for-mac-2007/GEN83769.html).

Note that they are not announcing a Quicken 2012 for Lion. They are merely promising a patched version of Quicken 2007.

Comment: Great! I saw that, too. Quicken 2007 for Lion with no new features would be a disappointment.

Answer (score 0):

[Squirrel](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/squirrel/id402403220?mt=12) is available in the Mac App Store and works quite nicely.

Answer (score 0):

moneydance is good, I've used it for 5 yrs. Makes good backups automatically, pretty easy to set it up the way you want.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Can you add more details and a link to this answer? Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.